# How to pass type into a function in PHP

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I have the following function to safely get a cookie:

```
public static function get_cookie($parameter, $default)
{
    return isset($_COOKIE[$parameter]) ? $_COOKIE[$parameter] : $default;
}
```

When I try to read `false` then use it in ternary operator, I see the value is treated as string (which is casted to `true`).

I want to pass a type into this function and cast the value, but have no ideas how.

**UPDATE**

As Niko pointed, casting 'false' to boolean doesn't work: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

I guess, I have to store strings in cookies always. (For instance, 'yes' and 'no' instead of 'false' and 'true' for my case).

Comment: Are you sure you're not passing it as a string to begin with?

Comment: Test the types of the parameters first with `gettype` http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: @John Conde Eh... passing what? Sorry for being dumb.

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the function and passing the parameter? It should be something like get_cookie(false, ....

Comment: @peacemaker I've already tested the result with gettype, it's string 'false' and $cookie ? 'a' : 'b' returns a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to do the casting inside the function (especially since PHP is loosely typed).

Consider the following use-case:

```
$booleanValue = ClassName::get_cookie('foo', true, 'bool');
```

You end up with the same amount of code (but much more readable!) when you do the casting outside of `get_cookie()`:

```
$booleanValue = (bool) ClassName::get_cookie('foo', true);
```

---

However, you can still implement a simple switch for 'false' and 'true' strings, respectively:

```
public static function get_cookie($parameter, $default, $isPseudoBool = false) {
    $value = isset($_COOKIE[$parameter]) ? $_COOKIE[$parameter] : $default;

    if ($isPseudoBool) {
        $value = ($value === true || strcasecmp($value, 'true') === 0);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

---

If you still prefer to move the type conversion into the function, `settype()` is what you need for this:

```
public static function get_cookie($parameter, $default, $type) {
    $value = isset($_COOKIE[$parameter]) ? $_COOKIE[$parameter] : $default;
    settype($value, $type);
    return $value;
}
```

But please note that this won't convert a string "false" to the boolean value `false`, if you specify `$type = 'bool'` - the conversion rules are the same as when an implicit conversion is done by the interpreter.

Comment: Good point. Thank you. I mean casting outside of the function. Hardcoding isType1, isType2... doesn't seem to be good idea.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I'd still prefer passing type as not optional parameter to get rid of this sort of bugs. What if I forget to cast.

Comment: @noober I've added a version that accepts a parameter for the desired type of the return value. But still, I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: Oh, settype. I had to find it myself. Thank you again. I think, explicit type passing is safer a lot. Especially, for me, as I don't like PHP variant-like typing at all (just have never faced problems with it before today).

Comment: "this won't convert a string "false" to the boolean value false" Damned! You are right! http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: @noober But that's actually a situation where it comes in handy that you want to move the conversion into the function. Just add a check for `$type == 'bool'` and `$value === 'true'` (and false, respectively) and do the conversion manually for those cases.

Comment: Now I think I just have to avoid not string values at all. That is reflected in my update to the question.

Comment: Also, if that is possible, you can replace the string "true" by "1" and "false" by "0" - because `(bool) "0" === false` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static function get_cookie($parameter, $default)
{

    if( empty($parameter) ) return $default;       

    return isset($_COOKIE[$parameter]) ? $_COOKIE[$parameter] : $default;
}
```